# Mounting a solderless tie point

Tags: pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly

I have an application where popping some solderless tie points on a PCB is a thing to to.  I picked up some 1x4 tie points, https://www.elexp.com/ProductDetails.aspx?item_no=03TB-IVR&CatId=

[image]

The issue is mounting.  There is a flimsy single lead on the back, with a plastic post at each end-- a longer one near the lead, and a slightly shorter one at the other end.

[image]

I can't find any real data sheet for the part.  Are these heat-posts??  If so, the plan for my Very small run (maybe 50 boards) would be a soldering iron with a spade tip.  Any forseeable problems?

Comment: Given that the two posts are different lengths and one is quite close to the metal lead, I suspect these are not intended to be melted.  I think you'll have more luck by securing these with epoxy (not superglue!).

Comment: @Wossname - That or press-fit.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, Possibly, but those legs don't appear to have a chamfer at the end which might make press fitting rather difficult as the plastic will likely deform and consequently not fit into the hole.  Press fitting hole sizes are very difficult to get right first time.  If the datasheet specifies a PCB hole diameter then that should be used in any case.

Comment: Just curious *why* the manufacturer would only expose one pin.  They easily could have exposed five, increasing strength.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't yet found a "datasheet", but I did find a 3M catalog page for their equivalent part  --  https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/3M%20PDFs/Solderless%20Breadboard%20Acces.pdf.  They specify the posts are 0.062, for press fit into  No. 53 drill holes.  We'll see if these guys actually match that.

Answer (score 2):

They may be intended to fit a mating plastic part. But you can still melt them if enough material sticks through the PCB.

I had a similar issue with heat posts and simply turned an aluminum melting tool that fit a soldering iron end. It has concave hole to spread the post out and a stop to keep the thickness from being decreased too much.

Worked a treat, and if you have a lathe handy it will almost take less time than it does to describe.

Be sure to set the temperature no higher than it needs to be (maybe start off around 230°C) and keep the area well ventilated.